# Added trendlines appear in legend but not in chart

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I created a scatter plot chart in Excel and added trendlines, but they are not displayed even though legend entries are created. How do I make them show up on the chart?

[image: Screenshot of Excel chart with ~50 trendline legend entries and 0 trendlines shown on the chart, with sidebar open to confirm the Y-axis ranges are automatic.]

These trendlines are ghosts; there are no corresponding entries in the chart object selection drop-down:
[image]

Also worth noting this doesn't apply to Moving Average, just Linear/Exponential/Linear Forecast:
[image: Screenshot of same chart in Excel with moving average trendline displayed on chart.]

The data is very simple: X is time, Y is numeric.
[image: Screenshot of data selector and source data in background]
[image: Screenshot of column formatting for X-axis source (Custom - h:mm:ss)]

It seems to be uncommon but not unheard of:

- [This answer at mrexcel](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/line-not-visible-on-chart.1168838/) doesn't apply because the chart object selection doesn't list any trendlines on this chart
- [This answer at excelforums](https://www.excelforum.com/excel-charting-and-pivots/549026-some-charts-will-not-show-trendlines.html) doesn't apply because I'm not using secondary axes
- [This ancient user](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/trendline-does-not-show-up-in-chart-does-in-legend.412929/) reports a similar problem but since they were able to modify the trendline color, it seems to be a different situation (I can change *legend entry* options, but not *trendline* options bc, you know, they don't exist)

> Link to original source file (expires 6 days): https://filebin.net/9somcg209wxhbjsk

Answer (score 0):

Change x-data to time only (without date) - data from column C.
Remove the chart and recreate it. There are too many trendlines in one chart.
Add one (or a few) trendline and format it according to your needs.
[image: Chart with trendline]
This screenshot illustrates your problem.
[image: Trendlines]

Comment: Thanks for the input. The question fully applies when using just one trendline but yes that's probably too many. Changing the X range from date+time to just time does produce a trendline but that's not a general solution (i.e. data must not span midnight) so I hesitate to mark this as an answer.

Comment: If the `x` data is for a period that spans midnight, you can subtract the date of the first point so that the values in the `x`-range are commensurate with the width of the range. At the moment, the `x`-range includes very close to each other large numbers, and this causes the trend line to be falsified.

Comment: No.. since posting the question I have managed to produce scatterplots with trendlines where the x data are datetime values but not consistently or reliably. Sometimes the trendlines are plotted, but nowhere near the data they "fit" and sometimes they are plotted correctly with no errors at all.